# How to start debugging memory issues in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a Rails application hosted on Heroku with barely any users, but I've been watching in agony as the memory ticks slowly upward. Right now on one dyno I'm at 150% and on the other 130%.

This seems indicative of a memory leak to me.

But I have no idea how to begin debugging this. I had turned on the Heroku Lab's memory logging but since the uptick is so slow it doesn't point anywhere obvious.

Where should I even begin?

**EDIT:**

I followed the answer Raajarshi linked me to and mapped `ObjectSpace`. These were the worst offenders:

`String=>135325, RubyVM::InstructionSequence=>35684, Array=>30744, ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode::Codepoint=>24430, Hash=>5341, Proc=>4609, RubyVM::Env=>4458, Class=>4315, Regexp=>2620, Module=>1803, MIME::Type=>1643, Gem::Requirement=>1282, Range=>938, Gem::Dependency=>906, ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat=>577, Pathname=>446, Rails::Paths::Path=>339, Rails::Initializable::Initializer=>282, Gem::Version=>270`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311930/how-can-i-find-a-memory-leak-on-heroku may be this can help you

Comment: Use the gem called gc_tracer, this not only tracks the garbage collection but also the memory allocation parts... This was a good reference for me .. http://samsaffron.com/archive/2014/04/08/ruby-2-1-garbage-collection-ready-for-production